# How to add point to a freqpoly plot?

Tags: r

I draw a frequency plot with geom_freqpoly :

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=time,color=type))
+geom_freqpoly(size=1.3,binwidth=2160) 
+theme_bw()+scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"), labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

I want to add point to the plot like:
[image]

How to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and figured out that we can tell geom_point() to use the same bins and counts as geom_freqpoly() like this:

```html
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=0.25) +
  geom_point(stat="bin", aes(y=..count..), binwidth=0.25)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me, though it doesn't correspond to the appropriate values and thus messed up my axes.

**Here is my code**:

```
    Data_Freq.Poly.1 <- 
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Data)) +
  labs(x = "Data", y = "Frequency", title = "Frequency Polygon of the Data Provided") +
  geom_freqpoly(center = 67.5,
                bins = 7,
                colour = "black") +
  geom_point(stat = "bin",
             aes(y = ..count..),
             bins = 7) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(39.5, 95.5, by = 8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:12)) +
  theme_classic() 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                face = "bold",
                                size = 16))

    Data_Freq.Poly.1
```

**Here is my graph**:
[Why are the points **not** on the line?][1]

**Here is what it should look like**:
[I've had to add the points manually on my tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfvoY.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).